# Get from Paris to Premiere Classe Bordeaux

Tags: trains, public-transport, france

I am now staying in Paris, and I will go to a hotel to stay in Bordeaux in a few days time, the hotel is located in Rue Du Professeur Jeanneney.

My problem is that I don't know how to go there after I come out from the Bordeaux high speed train station, there seems to be no information on Google Maps as to how to use public transport to move from one location to another.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you arriving in Gare de Bordeaux-Saint-Jean, or a different station?

Comment: Also, Google Maps seems [quite happy to offer me public transport directions](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=Gare+de+Bordeaux+Saint-Jean,+Rue+de+Tauzia,+Bordeaux,+France+to+Rue+du+Professeur+Jeanneney,+Talence,+France&hl=en&sll=44.814845,-0.572748&sspn=0.045544,0.130978&geocode=FbAFrAIdiYH3_yFibRpcVvzf_A%3BFaadqwIdQx33_ynrdN9JbSdVDTH2E29U_fICKg&oq=gare++to+Rue+Du+Professeur+Jeanneney&dirflg=r&ttype=now&noexp=0&noal=0&sort=def&t=m&z=14&start=0) between that station and the road with your hotel...

Comment: @Gagravarr - The Première Classe hotel is located on the other street of the same name in the area. Bordeaux is quite confusing sometimes ([Google directions](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?saddr=Gare+de+Bordeaux+Saint-Jean,+Rue+de+Tauzia,+Bordeaux,+France&daddr=Rue+du+Professeur+Georges+Jeanneney,+33300+Bordeaux,+France+(H%C3%B4tel+Premi%C3%A8re+Classe+Bordeaux+Nord+-+Lac)&hl=en&ie=UTF8&sll=44.886199,-0.555646&sspn=0.006659,0.010772&geocode=FbAFrAIdiYH3_yFibRpcVvzf_A%3BFXTrrAIddoP3_yEfGLwLbAMnuQ&dirflg=r&ttype=now&noexp=0&noal=0&sort=def&mra=ls&t=m&start=1&z=13)).

Comment: Gagravarr, I though there is only one train station in Bordeaux connecting to Paris? I will be using a tgv train, not sure whether it helps to pin down the location..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The public transport company in Bordeaux is [TBC](http://www.infotbc.com/). You can search an itinerary from there. Unfortunately the site is in french only.

There are two Rue du Professeur Jeanneney that are known by the service: one in Bordeaux (north of train station), the other one in Talence (south of train station). According to [Première Classe site](http://www.premiereclasse.fr/hotel/fr/france/aquitaine/gironde/bordeaux.htm), the one featuring a Première Classe hotel is north.

The itinerary found is [tram C then bus 7](http://www.infotbc.com/journey/detail?nbbefore=0&nbafter=4&sens=1&criteria=1&walkspeed=50&hangdistance=600&usetransday=0&date=2012%7C05%7C04&modetype=tramway;bus;coach;local_train;train&time=20%7C15&departure=StopArea%7C532%7CGare%20Saint-Jean%7CBordeaux%7C%7C%7C371123,00%7C1984790,00%7C944!0!2;&arrival=Address%7C2531%7Cdu%20Professeur%20Georges%20Jeanneney%7CBordeaux%7C%7Crue%7C371349,48%7C1991651,19%7C!!;).